# Rearguard vent issue on Kenmore gas range

Tags: gas, range, venting

Vent in rearguard of gas range is outputting too much heat on top of stove; can we adjust this? it was changed when range was moved recently.

Comment: Can you change it back? Sounds like this change was made intentionally...

Comment: we heard a popping noise when we were sliding it back, the gap looks bigger now; we aren't sure how much force to use or if we should take it apart and do something else

Comment: Overall, I don't understand your question. When using the oven heat is expected to come out of the rear guard unless your definition of rearguard is different than mine. If you had less heat before then that sounds like it might have been a fire hazard waiting to happen. Can you post pictures?

Comment: The stove has been in use since 2005, i dont think it's a fire hazard. The heat is much greater now, and oven takes longer to bake food, so our conclusion is that we increased the venting from the oven onto the stove top. I guess my question is if this new gap/ventis owner fixable ?

Comment: You'll have to inspect your oven and possibly remove the rearguard to verify that everything is as it should be. You said the gap is bigger now so I would imagine you should return it to normal. See https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/oven-vents-way-too-much-heat.191653/

Comment: I think the point @MonkeyZeus is trying to make is "put it back the way it was before it was moved". Too much heat escaping _now_ could be a fire hazard, not the amount that's been escaping since 2005 and prior to the move.

Comment: @FreeMan and atMonkeyZeus oh, yes, the heat now is not acceptable and risky; we are grilling outside until we get it fixed. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you for the link/info, i will carefully take stove apart tonight after work